# Assert toHaveBeenCalledWith with a React input components onChange handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am working on a test that checks that a React input component's `onChange` handler is called. I am using React 17, the react-testing-library, and jest.

```js
const Input = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
};
```

```js
test("calling onChange works", () => {
  const value = "default value";
  const handleChange = jest.fn();
  handleChange.mockImplementation((e) =>
    console.log("value is correct here", e.target.value)
  );

  const { container } = render(<Input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />);

  const input = container.querySelector("input");
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "new value" } });

  // works
  expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalled();

  /// does not work
  expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
      target: expect.objectContaining({
        value: "new value"
      })
    })
  );
});
```

The first assertion, checking that the handler was called, works, but I am not able to assert that the event properly contains the new value. Interestingly, mocking the implementation shows that the correct value is being passed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-react-forked-7gytg?file=/src/components/Input.test.js:116-763

**I am aware that it would be easier to test the parent form component, seeing if the new input is displayed**; however, I would like to unit test this individual component if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's ok to put your assertion(s) in the mock implementation. I have something similar, testing a checkbox component.

```
it('should raise on onChange event when there is a state change', () => {
    let spy = jest.fn();
    spy.mockImplementation((e) => {
        expect(e.target.checked).toBe(true);
        expect(e.target.value).toBe('foo');
    })
    render(<Checkbox value={'foo'} checked={false} onChange={spy} />);
    
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('checkbox')); 

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

If you put in an assertion that you know will fail and see the test fail, you know they're getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is is because you have a controlled input where you are always having the value of input as `default value` if you remove `value={value}` from your input it will get pass.

Your `handleChange` might be updating the state which will also change the value of input but when you define `const value = 'default value'` it is never going to change even if you trigger onChange event.

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "react-testing-library";
import Input from "./Input";

test("calling onChange works", () => {
  const handleChange = jest.fn();
  handleChange.mockImplementation((e) =>
    console.log("value is correct here", e.target.value)
  );

  const { container } = render(<Input onChange={handleChange} />);

  const input = container.querySelector("input");
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "new value" } });

  // works
  expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalled();

  /// works now
  expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
      target: expect.objectContaining({
        value: "new value"
      })
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that this results in the input becoming uncontrolled. It's also not very viable because the input component requires a value prop.